# How to Echo Multidimensional Comparison Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array:

```
$one = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Southampton
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Manchester United F.C
        )

)
```

and

```
$two = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [number] => 25555
            [slice_1] => 4
            [slice_2] => 4
            [slice_3] => 2
            [slice_4] => 4
            [status] => Published
        )

)
```

I want to output, if array `$two->slice_1` same as array `$one->id` than output `$one->name`.

For example:

`$two[0]->slice_1` (4) compare to `$one[0]->id` (4) will result in Manchester United F.C.

Because the array `$one` and `$two` will be have more than one array. Please don't answer this:

```
if($two[0]->slice_1 == $one[1]->id){echo $one[0]->name;}
```

I'm stucking here and can't think out some way. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: what have your tryed so far?

Comment: I have tried : 

`$count = count($two);
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
   
   if($two[$i]->slice_1 == $one[$i]->id ){
    echo $two[$i]->slice_1.' : '.$one[$i]->name;
   
   
  }`

Answer (score 0):

avoiding loops inside loops first create temp reference array then loop though second array outputting the result

```
foreach($one as $id=>$data){
   $temp[$data['id']] = $data['name'];
}
foreach($two as $secondary_id=>$secondary_data){
  echo isset($temp[$secondary_data['slice_1']]) ? $temp[$secondary_data['slice_1']] : ''; 
}
```